# Excel VBA Transpose an array and declare to another sheet range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have some Excel VBA code which generates an array based on inputs/calculations and then enters the values onto another sheet.

I have this working for one version of my spreadsheet which contains all of the calculations on one sheet using:

```
Range(Cells(4, "T"), Cells(4 + ball, "T")).Value = Application.Transpose(lon)
```

However, when I try to use this on another workbook which enters the values onto another sheet in the same location using:

```
Sheets("Calculations").Range(Cells(4, "T"), Cells(4 + ball, "T")).Value = Application.Transpose(lon)
```

I get an error stating: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".  I have looked this up and also doing some debug.print of values in my array to ensure I understand the values and the length, believe my issue is with how I am declaring the range.  However, I cannot seem to figure out the correct implementation.

As a work-around I have a For loop pasting the values into the cell but it seems to me there would be a cleaner way to do this.

```
For n = 1 To ball
    Sheets("Calculations").Cells(4 + n, "T").Value = lon(n)
Next n
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cells object is not fully qualified.

While your range is referring to `Sheets("Calculations")` in `Sheets("Calculations").Range` but the `Cells` are referring to the `ActiveSheet`.

You can either do

```
Sheets("Calculations").Range(Sheets("Calculations").Cells(4, "T"), Sheets("Calculations").Cells(4 + ball, "T")).Value=Application.Transpose(lon)
```

or (Notice the dots before Cells Object)

```
With Sheets("Calculations")
    .Range(.Cells(4, "T"), .Cells(4 + ball, "T")).Value = Application.Transpose(lon)
End With
```

Comment: Just to piggy back on the comment about the dots before `.cells`.  It's important you don't forget those, otherwise you could get some errors when using multiple worksheets.  I've had too many headaches caused by simply not adding the `.` when using `Range()` and `With()` statements.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you for your help.  I would have never realized that extra reference on the cells.  I took your first suggestion just so that when I am looking at the code in the future it will be clear what I am referencing and also like BruceWayne notes, I would probably miss those "." when using them in the future.